# How to compute the number of trainable paramters of a 3D convolution layer?

Tags: parameters, 3d, deep-learning, convolution

I'm a beginner in the CNN, I’m using 3D convolution layer when building my network, but I’m not able to understand how the trainable parameters of this convolution3D layer are computed. Here is an example of a simple one-layer network with an input shape (3,16,112,112) (channels, frames, height, width), i.e 16 RGB images of size (112*112):

```
def get_model(summary=False):

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', 
                        padding='valid', name='conv1',
                        strides=(1, 1, 1), 
                        input_shape=(3, 16, 112, 112)))
if summary:
    print(model.summary())
return model
```

The summary displays 5248 trainable parameters, could anyone explain to me how this number is resulted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trainable parameters refer to all the weights and biases within your network along with values in the convolutional filters in your 3D convolutional layers. This means that there are 5248 different connection weights, biases and values in the convolutional filters that are trainable.

Networks may also have parts of it which are non-trainable such as a max pooling layer. What this layer does is not affected by training.

Number of weights = kernel width * kernel height * kernel depth (because 3d) x number of channels in input image * number of kernels

Number of biases = number of kernels

So for you:

Number of weights = 3 x 3 x 3 x 3 x 64 = 5184

Number of biases = 64

Number of parameters = 5184 + 64 = 5248

Comment: @convollutionBoy Thank you for your response, I know that these 5248 are the trainable ones, but I wonder how to calculate them? I found examples that explain how to compute the number of parameters in 2D convolution layer, but with 3D convolution layers, it is not the same way to compute the parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I'm looking for. :)